# jQuery hover/hide/show - not all the text will disappear correctly when mousing over multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m in this situation, where I would like to have a default text show on my site and when hovering over three different images then the default text should change to three different texts.

I made this happen, as you can see in my fiddle - but if i quickly move my mouse over all three images, then not all the text will disappear correctly. How do I achieve this?

My JavaScript code for a Image:

```
$().ready(function () {
 $("#image1").hover(

 function () {
     $("#default").hide(timer,

     function () {
         $("#content1").show(timer,

         function () {})
     });
 },

 function () {
     $("#content1").hide(timer, function () {
         $("#default").show(timer,

         function () {});
     });
 });
});
```

ps. If this is possible with HTML and CSS alone - that is also okay.

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T4BCx/4/

Comment: have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SySgr/4/

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Yes, follow Arun's code.  MUCH better.  There's no need to the document.ready four times.  It's only ready once per load.

Comment: Arun -> Super ill mark it as an answer then.
btw. What is this data-target? (is there anywhere i can read up on it?)
Dan -> okay, now thinking about it, i should have seen that one :) but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of the queuing nature of animation commands, in your case you need to force jQuery to complete all the previously queued animation before showing/hiding an element. You can use [.stop()](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SySgr/) to do this.

Also your solution looks quite complecated, I've made some dom changes also to make it simple

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" id="image1" alt="description" width="150px" class="content-img" data-target="#content1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" id="image2" alt="description" width="150px" class="content-img" data-target="#content2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" id="image3" alt="description" width="150px" class="content-img" data-target="#content3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="height:100px">
            <div id="default">
                 <h1>default</h1>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="content1">
                 <h1>content 1</h1>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="content2">
                 <h1>content 2</h1>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="content3">
                 <h1>content 3</h1>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
//initial
var timer = 200;
jQuery(function ($) {
    var inside = false;
    $("#content1, #content2, #content3").hide();
    $(".content-img").hover(function () {
        inside = true;
        var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
        $("#default").stop(true, true).hide(timer, function () {
            if (inside) {
                $target.stop(true, true).show(timer);
            }
        });
    }, function () {
        inside = false;
        $($(this).data('target')).stop(true, true).hide(timer, function () {
            if (!inside) {
                $("#default").stop(true, true).show(timer);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SySgr/)

Comment: Much more simple and perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like this

```
$("img").hover(function () {
    var value = $(this).attr("id").substr($(this).attr("id").length-1);
    $('div[id="default"]').find('h1').text("Content" + value);
    $('div[id="default"]').find('p').text("Content of Image" + value);
});

$("img").mouseout(function(){
$('div[id="default"]').find('h1').text("Default");
    $('div[id="default"]').find('p').text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
})
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4BCx/6/)